# How to apply Convolution1D in 4D input multiple times on one dimension

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, conv-neural-network

Assuming I have the following layers in keras:

```
def _initialize_conv_layer(name):
    conv1 = Convolution1D(filters=1000,
                          kernel_size=5,
                          activation="relu",
                          name="conv_" + name,
                          padding="valid") 
    conv2 = GlobalMaxPooling1D(name="max_pool_" + name)
    conv3 = Activation("relu", name="act_" + name)
    conv4 = Dropout(rate=0.1, name="dropout_" + name)
    z = Dense(100, name="vector" + name)
    return conv1, conv2, conv3, conv4, z
```

and:

```
def _get_vector(self, input_, conv1, conv2, conv3, conv4, z):
    i1 = conv1(input_)
    i2 = conv2(i1)
    i3 = conv3(i2)
    i4 = conv4(i3)
    vector_ = z(i4)
    return vector_
```

also:

```
conv1, conv2, conv3, conv4, z = _initialize_conv_layer("message")
z1 = _get_vector(embedded_sequences, conv1, conv2, conv3, conv4, z)
```

where:

- `embedded_sequences` is an embedding of dimension: `(batch_size, 200, 100)`.
- `z1` is the output of dimension: `(batch_size, 100)`

My question is how to apply the same conv in(not to create a new conv):

```
z2 = _get_vector(embedded_sequences2, conv1, conv2, conv3, conv4, z)
```

- `embedded_sequences2` of dimension: `(batch_size, 50, 200, 100)`
- `z2` output dimension: `(batch_size, 50, 100)`

In a point of view what I want is to apply the same convolution to each row in the second dimension(length of 50).

My understanding is that I should apply a `TimeDistributed` inside a `Lambda` function. Or maybe with some reshaping the data? Is that correct or not?

Any idea how to do it?